# PHP MySQL Options using JOIN

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table...

Table: **forums**

```
for_id  for_name       for_des           for_mem
  1      Forum 1    Description 1     mem1@email.com, mem2@email.com 
  2      Forum 2    Description 2       null
  3      Forum 3    Description 3     mem1@email.com
```

Then i have another table: **members**

```
mem_id mem_name     mem_email ...
   1     Jane    mem1@email.com
   2     Jack    mem2@email.com
   3     Smith   mem3@email.com
```

I am trying to create an HTML Options list. A multi select list that would display all columns in **members** and then select those in a **forums** when editing the information.

Example: Editing **for_id = 1** 
It should display all users and select only users who are in **for_id=1**'s **for_mem**

Currently i am using:

```
<? $data = explode(',',$row[for_mem]); ?>
<div class="col-md-9">
    <select name="for_mem" id="" multiple class="form-control">
        <?php foreach($data as $key => $value){?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

But it only displays the users in the for_mem for that Forum, not all users for them to select new ones to add. Also, just the email. Is there a way to display the name?

Please help. Thanks

Comment: I dont understand @HiteshMundra, i added an Example. Does that expalin things better? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This query can solve partly & then join both by union. first part is members that are exist in forums and second part members that are not exist for the forums.
I have added a field "checked" which is 1 for first part and 0 for second part used for identified which users to checked when display.

```
select for_id, for_name, for_mem, mem_name, mem_email, 1 checked from forums, members where locate(mem_email, for_mem) > 0
union
select for_id, for_name, for_mem, mem_name, mem_email, 0 checked from forums, members where locate(mem_email, for_mem) = 0;
```

may be there any syntactically mistake i haven't tested because of data unavailable. You can use `group by or group concat` for more. I advice to run it on mysql prompt first and see the result and modify as your need.